# RecyclerView call only constructor

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

I'm trying to setup recyclerview and it was worked before but not not work

here how i setup it

```
public void setupRecyclerView() {
    try{
        RealmResults<Order> orderRealmResults = myRealm.where(Order.class).sort("timestamp", Sort.DESCENDING).findAll();
        Order order = orderRealmResults.get(positionO);

        RealmList<Product> products = order.getProducts();
      

        RealmResults<Product> results = products.where().equalTo("status", 1).findAll();

        recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.products_rv);
        listAdapter = new ProductsListAdapter(this, myRealm, results, positionO,status);

        recyclerView.setLayoutManager((new LinearLayoutManager(this)));
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(listAdapter);
        listAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }catch (Exception e){
        Log.d("orders_data", "order in main: exception :  " + "MainActivity");
        e.printStackTrace();

    }

}
```

And here is my Adapter

```
public class ProductsListAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ProductsListAdapter.ViewHolder> {

    private static final String TAG = ProductsListAdapter.class.getSimpleName();
    private Context mContext;
    private Realm myRealm;
    private List<Product> productsData;
    private RealmResults<Product> products;
    private LayoutInflater layoutInflater;
    private ImageView prod_img;
    private TextView prod_name, prod_quantity, prod_unitPrice, prod_totalPrice, prod_barcode,prod_desc
            ,barcode_title,unit_price_title,total_price_title,Quantity_title;
    int positionO;
    MySharedPreferences mySharedPreferences;
    String mName,mPrice,mQuantity,mBarcode,mTotal,mDes;
    String status;

    public ProductsListAdapter(Context context, Realm realm, RealmResults<Product> products,int positionO,String status) {

        Log.d("orders_data", "order in main: productAdapter init"+ realm+" :: "+products.size()+" :: " +
                +positionO+ " :: "+status+" :: end");

        this.mContext = context;
        this.myRealm = realm;
        myRealm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();
        this.products = products;
        this.positionO = positionO;
        this.status = status;
        this.layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    }

    public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        private CardView cardView;

        public ViewHolder(CardView v) {
            super(v);
            cardView = v;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return products.size();
    }

    @Override
    public ProductsListAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(
            ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        Log.d("orders_data", "order in main: productAdapter onCreateViewHolder");
        CardView cv = (CardView) LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.product_item, parent, false);
        return new ViewHolder(cv);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, @SuppressLint("RecyclerView") int position) {

        mySharedPreferences = MySharedPreferences.getInstance(mContext);
        mySharedPreferences.getLanguageKey();

        Log.d("orders_data", "order in main: productAdapter");

        CardView cardView = holder.cardView;

        barcode_title = cardView.findViewById(R.id.barcode_title);
        unit_price_title = cardView.findViewById(R.id.unit_price_title);
        total_price_title = cardView.findViewById(R.id.total_price_title);
        Quantity_title = cardView.findViewById(R.id.Quantity_title);

        prod_img = cardView.findViewById(R.id.product_img);
        prod_name = cardView.findViewById(R.id.product_name);
        prod_quantity = cardView.findViewById(R.id.Quantity_value);
        prod_unitPrice = cardView.findViewById(R.id.price_unit_value);
        prod_totalPrice = cardView.findViewById(R.id.total_price_value);
        prod_barcode = cardView.findViewById(R.id.barcode);
        prod_desc = cardView.findViewById(R.id.product_description);

        prod_name.setTypeface(HelperMethods.changeFont(mContext));
        prod_quantity.setTypeface(HelperMethods.changeFont(mContext));
        prod_unitPrice.setTypeface(HelperMethods.changeFont(mContext));
        prod_totalPrice.setTypeface(HelperMethods.changeFont(mContext));
        prod_barcode.setTypeface(HelperMethods.changeFont(mContext));
        prod_desc.setTypeface(HelperMethods.changeFont(mContext));

        barcode_title.setTypeface(HelperMethods.changeFont(mContext));
        unit_price_title.setTypeface(HelperMethods.changeFont(mContext));
        total_price_title.setTypeface(HelperMethods.changeFont(mContext));
        Quantity_title.setTypeface(HelperMethods.changeFont(mContext));


        Product product = products.get(position);

        mName = product.getName();
        mQuantity = product.getNeededQuantity();
        mPrice = product.getOldUnitPrice();
        mTotal = product.getTotalPrice();
        mBarcode = product.getBarCode();
        mDes = product.getDescription();


        prod_name.setText(mName);
        prod_quantity.setText(mQuantity);
        prod_unitPrice.setText(mPrice);
        prod_totalPrice.setText(mTotal);
        if (product.getBarCode()!=null && !product.getBarCode().isEmpty()){
            prod_barcode.setText(mBarcode);
        }else{
            prod_barcode.setText("0000000000000");
        }

        prod_desc.setText(mDes);
        prod_desc.setTextColor(Color.rgb(225,112,77));

        GlideApp.with(mContext)
                .load(product.getImage())
                .into(prod_img);


        holder.cardView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(mContext,ProductDetailsActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("positionO", positionO);
                intent.putExtra("positionP", position);
                intent.putExtra("status", status);
                mContext.startActivity(intent);



            }
        });

    }


}
```

I didn't know what's wrong in the code?! but the weird is this code used to work and I didn't changes is but also it was an old code it passed 2 years from last edit on it.
I debug this code and I found it goes in the adapter constructor but not go on onCreateCiew method of the adapter or the onBindView

Comment: the adapter not work it didn't load the data and the onCreateViewHolder method didn't display the log message so it didn't called?

Comment: sure and the constructor of the adapter was called but nothing more

Comment: Try logging your products/results after setAdapter: ```Log.i("INFORMATION:" , "Data:" + results );```

Comment: I tried and it has a product with complete data